# How to generate frozen_inference_graphe.pb and .pbtxt files with tensorflow 2

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'd like to use my own tensorflow 2 / keras model with opencv (cv.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow(    bufferModel[, bufferConfig] ). But, I didn't manage to generate the required files :

bufferModel :   buffer containing the content of the pb file (frozen_inference_graphe)

bufferConfig : buffer containing the content of the pbtxt file (model configuration file)

Everything I've found rely on "freeze_graph.py" or other solution that only work with tensorflow 1.x. How should I do with tensorflow 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

The `.pb` file gets generated when using `keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint()`.
However, I don't know how to create the `.pbtxt` file.